# how to remove desktop switching box that appears

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments, gnome-panel

I want to remove this box that appears while switching desktop on my ubuntu machine. How can i do it? I am using Ubuntu 18.04
[image: this image.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extensions come to the rescue. The extension "[Disable Workspace Switcher Popup](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/959/disable-workspace-switcher-popup/)" unfortunately appears not actively maintained anymore, but still does the job even on recent versions of Gnome Shell.

An actively maintained extension, "[Just Perfection](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3843/just-perfection/)", allows to disable a bunch of things, including the Workspace Popup.

Comment: "just perfection" extension doesn't seem to support on my system. don't know why. every time i installed it. it restarted user interface and prompted user login page. and after entering correct log in credentials. it just again restarts gnome desktop ( not the whole system ) and prompts user login.

Comment: And what about the first extension mentionned?

Comment: that does the job. thanks @vanadium